# Empty result when parsing a JSON

Tags: php, json, stackexchange-api

This is the kind of question I hate asking because I know the answer must be super easy, but I can't seem to figure it out.

I am trying to parse the JSON response from the `Stack Exchange API` but I am getting an empty string as a result even though I checked the URL and also the JSON formatting and everything seems to be valid.

The code I am using is simply:

```
$surl = file_get_contents("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search?order=desc&sort=relevance&intitle=books&site=stackoverflow");

$json1 = json_decode($surl,true);

print_r($json1);
```

When I try to `echo` the content of `$surl` before `json_decode` I get a strange response full of `�` characters.

Any tip in the right direction will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string returned by the API call, [according to the Stack Exchange API documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) has been compressed.

> Additionally, all API responses are compressed. The Content-Encoding header is always set, but some proxies will strip this out. The proper way to decode API responses can be found here.

You will need to decompress the string first with [`gzdecode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzdecode.php) and then you'll be able to properly `json_decode()` it as you tried.

```
$surl = file_get_contents("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search?order=desc&sort=relevance&intitle=books&site=stackoverflow");

// Decode the compressed string
$surl = gzdecode($surl);

// Then you'll be able to json_decode() it...
$json1 = json_decode($surl, true);

print_r($json1);
// Prints:

Array
(
    [items] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [tags] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => research
                        )

                    [owner] => Array
                        (
                            [reputation] => 9995
                            [user_id] => 1944
                            [user_type] => registered
                            [accept_rate] => 93
                            [profile_image] => https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/93fc84c261cdce2e2f1d64c8e531ecb7?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG
                            [display_name] => Charles Roper
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! totally missed that. Thanks a lot Michael